# How to enable filestream in EF5 codefirst and database migrations

Tags: sql, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Silverlight business application that uses EF5 codefirst, the application is already installed on a client and now I need to upload and download files using sql filestream. I've been looking on how to do this and I found I have to enable filestream at the windows level and at the sql level. For the first it seems I have to use SQL Server Configuration manager and for the second I have found some scripts.

I wanted to make this migration as transparent to the client (and to the person installing my software update) as possible so this is my first question:

Can I enable filestream at windows level and at SQL level programmatically? (Without having to use SQL Server Configuration Manager or SQL Server Management Studio)

Also I need to support migrate my client db and create a new db (in case my app is installed on other new clients) supporting filestream (to store the uploaded files). So these are my other questions:

How can I create a filestream column using POCOs (what data type should I use for my property)?

If there is no support for filestream in EF5 (no Attributes or any other thing) so I have to use scripts then where to put those scripts for db creation and for db migration?

Are automatic migrations good for use in this case or should I use database migrations just to generate a script and then apply it manually on the client site?

Thank you very much in advance.

Juan Carlos